# How can I format this javascript code to take into consideration 2 different values?

Tags: javascript, format, decimal

I have a file that will contain values that could be the following:

```
0.000029
13000
```

For the value that is `0.00029` I do not want to format this, however for `13000` I want to show it as:

```
13,000.00
```

I have the following code:

```
Formatter.format(row["myValue"], "#,###.00#######");
```

This does format the above as:

```
13,000.00
```

However for `0.000029` it is dropping the first zero and showing it as `$.00002`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: JavaScript has a `Formatter` class?  Are you using a third-party library, or is this actually _Java_ that you're asking about?

Comment: @MattMorgan If it's Java, that's not correct syntax.

Comment: Try using `"#,##0.00#######"`

Comment: Again, is this vanilla JS, or some third party library?  Adding that information to the question would make it more helpful to future users.  As it stands, what is this question about? JavaScript, afaik, doesn't have a `Formatter` class.